# AS3 - navigateToURL issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have below code:

```
    botton_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onClick);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var url:String = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/signInDetail";
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    variables.query = ta.text;
    variables.packageId = 1;
    variables.update = "askADoctorSaveQuery";
    variables.task = "CHAT_PRE_ACTIONS_WITHOUT_PACKAGEID";
    variables.query = ta.text;
    request.data = variables;
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,compleHandler);
    loader.load(request);
}

function compleHandler(event:Event):void {
    var click_url2:String = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/ask-doctor-online";
    var request2:URLRequest = new URLRequest(click_url2);
    navigateToURL(request2, "_blank");

}
```

After the first request is loaded and compleHandler is called, the navigateToURL method opens the url in a popup instead of new tab. I am not sure what is the issue.

PLease help...

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line. This loads it into a new window.

```
 navigateToURL(request2, "_blank");
```

You have two other options:
In parent frame :

```
navigateToURL(request2, "_parent");
```

Replace current page :

```
navigateToURL(request2, "_self");
```

**EDIT**

After rechecking, I believe opening a window in a new tab is a user preference for the browser. There seems to be no way that a developer can control this. In IE 8 for example:

http://www.computershopper.com/feature/50-windows-7-tips-tweaks-and-secrets/open-a-link-in-a-new-tab-in-internet-explorer-8

Comment: This doesnot work. Infact the window or the URL doesnot open at all.

Comment: @VikashAgrawal This code should work. I have used it multiple times. I have double checked the documentation to be sure. Here look it up : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()

Comment: OKK I am not sure what was the problem but now it is working. But self or parent both are redirecting in smae tab. What i want here is the same window and a differnt tab.

Answer (score -1):

navigateToURL(request2, "_self");